# Reduce dimensionality in keras.Model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have this class that inherits from `tf.keras.Model`:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense

class Actor(tf.keras.Model):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.linear1 = Dense(128, activation = 'relu')
        self.linear2 = Dense(256, activation = 'relu')
        self.linear3 = Dense(3, activation = 'softmax')

    # model override method        
    def call(self, state):
        x = tf.convert_to_tensor(state)
        x = self.linear1(x)
        x = self.linear2(x)
        x = self.linear3(x)
        return x
```

it is used like this:

```
prob = self.actor(np.array([state]))
```

it works with (5,) input and returns (1,3) tensor which is what I expect

```
state: (5,) data: [0.50267935 0.50267582 0.50267935 0.50268406 0.5026817 ]
prob: (1, 3) data: tf.Tensor([[0.29540768 0.3525798  0.35201252]], shape=(1, 3), dtype=float32)
```

however if I pass a higher dimension input this return higher dimension tensor:

```
state: (5, 3) data: [[0.50789109 0.49648439 0.49651666]
 [0.5078905  0.49648391 0.49648928]
 [0.50788815 0.49648356 0.49643452]
 [0.50788677 0.4964834  0.49640713]
 [0.50788716 0.49648329 0.49635237]]
prob: (1, 5, 3) data: tf.Tensor(
[[[0.34579638 0.342928   0.3112757 ]
  [0.34579614 0.34292707 0.31127676]
  [0.34579575 0.34292522 0.31127906]
  [0.3457955  0.3429243  0.31128016]
  [0.34579512 0.34292242 0.3112824 ]]], shape=(1, 5, 3), dtype=float32)
```

But **I need it to be (1,3)** still. I never used raw keras models implemented like this. What can I do to fix it?

Tensorflow 2.9.1 with keras 2.9.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are working on a reinforcement learning problem. Try adding a `Flatten` layer to the beginning of your model (or a `Reshape` layer):

```
class Actor(tf.keras.Model):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.flatten = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()
        self.linear1 = Dense(128, activation = 'relu')
        self.linear2 = Dense(256, activation = 'relu')
        self.linear3 = Dense(3, activation = 'softmax')

    # model override method        
    def call(self, state):
        x = tf.convert_to_tensor(state)
        x = self.flatten(x)
        x = self.linear1(x)
        x = self.linear2(x)
        x = self.linear3(x)
        return x
```

Also check the [design](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Dense) of the `Dense` layer:

> Note: If the input to the layer has a rank greater than 2, then Dense computes the dot product between the inputs and the kernel along the last axis of the inputs and axis 0 of the kernel (using tf.tensordot). For example, if input has dimensions (batch_size, d0, d1), then we create a kernel with shape (d1, units), and the kernel operates along axis 2 of the input, on every sub-tensor of shape (1, 1, d1) (there are batch_size * d0 such sub-tensors). The output in this case will have shape (batch_size, d0, units).